# get %APPDATA% path using c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to get the path to the `%APPDATA%` folder.

In win 2000 & xp it's in: `C:\Documents and Settings\user name\Application Data`

In vista & win7 it's in: `C:\Users\user name\AppData\Roaming`

I know there is the function [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it retrieves a BOOL
and I want to get the path as a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third parameter of [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), named `lpszPath`, is marked as `__out`.

Something like this should do:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
BOOL result = SHGetSpecialFolderPath( hWnd
                                    , buffer
                                    , CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA
                                    , false );
if(!result) throw "You'll need error handling here!";
std::wcout << buffer;
```

Note: I haven't done any Win API work in years. Very likely someone comes along shortly pointing out where I blew it.

Comment: Using this cout gives "002BFA00"

Comment: @Tom: That happens when you compile as Unicode; you'd need `std::wcout` there. You now hit the `TCHAR[MAX_PATH] -> `wchar_t*` -> `void*` conversion, and print the address of the stack buffer. Just use `MessageBox`, it's an example anyway.

Comment: straight up, thanks for that MSalters. doing the conversion from Java to c++ ain't easy at all. any knowledge about flipping this to std::string?

Comment: @Tom: If you have compiled as MBCS instead of as Unicode, then you can just construct a std::string straight from buffer. If you are using Unicode then you will need to use a stringstream to perform the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for replying DeadMG, reading all about it in my c++ reference book now